# How can I create a desicion tree in php using these data felds?

Tags: php, html

So the assignment wants us to make a decision tree based on 3 to 4 variables.
there is supposed to be a result for each of these values.

The first file is an HTML document has a form with drop down menus.
For each combination of 3 variables color, size, and shape. There needs to be a echo out of something like a fruit. So if user selects (shape circle) (color red) and (size medium) that the output becomes apple for example.

so I am thinking multiple if statements inside each other but how? I tried and so far no luck. So how should the PHP be done?

```
HTML CODE
----------
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
<!--this is a simple fieldset with the dropboxes put in them-->
<fieldset>
  <legend>Select your fruit!</legend>


<form class="" action="tree.php" method="post">
  <select name="Color">
    <option value="Blank"></option>
    <option value="Red">Red</option>
    <option value="Purple">Purple</option>
    <option value="Yellow">Yellow</option>
  </select>

  <select name="Size">
    <option value="Blank"></option>
    <option value="Small">Small</option>
    <option value="Medium">Medium</option>
    <option value="Large">Large</option>
  </select>

  <select name="Shape">
    <option value="Blank"></option>
    <option value="Round">Round</option>
    <option value="Square">Square</option>
    <option value="Elipse">Elipse</option>
  </select>
  <input type="submit" />
</form>

</fieldset>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

first create a master table with possible result set where the table may have fields like "Shape | Color | Size | Fruit Name" . Now catch each of the drop-down value on submit and catch them in the tree.php page . Now search the master table for result with the values obtained and echo the result you will get from the database .

If you do not want to use a database then you have to use multiple if-else statements or switch case which will definitely shorten your codes .